# Firebase Storage Read/Write Bandwidth Question

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I've been looking on the Firebase Storage documentation pages and other places on what actions exactly are considered read/writes because my bandwidth was raising fairly quickly and was curious, but not able to find anything exact.

Once a user uploads a photo within the android application, the https link to the image stored in firebase (`https://firebasestorage.....`) is then saved as a field under the user in the real-time database to access later. The image is then loaded into an ImageView with the URL, which other users can click a button on that users section and it opens up that image in a pop-up. Instead of calling the `getDownloadUrl()` from firebase storage again I just use the already stored https link to it from when the user uploaded it.

I'm wondering if every time a user clicks the button to open that image in a dialog, and it loads that https firebase link, is that what is considered as a read operation too? and not just using the `getDownloadUrl()`?
It also spiked higher once I uploaded a video, and then accessed that video in storage by its https link, but I have a feeling they are related reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a client downloads the data for a file from Cloud Storage, your project is charged for the bandwidth of sending the data from the server to that client. It really is as simple as that.

So unless you client caches the data when it reads it for the first time, repeatedly loading the same URL will indeed lead to repeated charges for the download bandwidth that is consumes.